# How can I power a 5 V DC motor with an 18 V 4.7 mA supply?

Tags: power, current

I want to power a 5 V DC motor with a power supply rated for 18 V and 4.7 mA. How can I make it 8 V / 5 V, 500 mA current to run the motor?

Comment: You can't create power out of thin air. Roughly 85 mW in can't give you 2.5 W out (at 5 V), let alone 4 W (at 8 V)

Comment: In addition to Finbarr's point: what's the 8 V for? Is this a 5 V motor? And an 18 V 4.7 mA supply wouldn't be particularly useful; are you sure you have the input supply rating right?

Comment: You can probably power a 5V motor with an 18V power supply with PWM, if you're okay with voiding the warranty, but that won't help you with the current.

Comment: Charge a large capacitor to 18V at 4.7mA. When it's fully charged, it can supply a 5V buck convertor to run the motor for a short burst. Then you'll have to wait until it's charged again.

Answer (score 3):

Impossible.

Your input power is only 0.085 W. You need 4 W. You can't create 4 W out of 0.085 W. It's against the laws of physics.